# How to use QueryDef to set a name

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to export a query to excel from my access database. There are  few rules and conditions I have to follow to ensure I get the correct information.

The biggest hurdle is having to choose which object name to export. I am managing a system for 8 town and each town has multiple naming conventions for their system. I need to export the information showing the naming convention requested by the town.

What I did first was to create query with all the information in it that I would need. Then I did create table from the query getting it to export as a table. From there I used TableDef to change the name of the name field (example = "name1" to "Name") to a more professional look. Finally based on which name needs to be present I delete the field names that are not required and export to excel.

I found this QueryDef which runs what appears the same way but has an issue when renaming the field.

```
Select Case displayName
    Case Is = "Name 1"
        db.QueryDefs(queryName).Fields("name1").name = "Name"
        db.QueryDefs(queryName).Fields("name2").VisibleValue = False
    Case Else
        MsgBox ("Name does not extist in system")
End Select
```

I expect the "name1" field to "Name" but I get "Invalid Operation Error"

Comment: I highly advise not running DDL commands like `ALTER` for Excel reports. I am not understanding many of your issues as all can be handled with queries: you can change column names with queries using `AS` operator (no need to change table names); you can specify needed columns in `SELECT` clause (no need to drop columns); and you can export Access queries to Excel (no need for creating tables).

Comment: I didnt want to do the ```docmd.CreateQuery``` command and hard code the query. There will be more information added and potentially removed later on. It would seem too that you cannot perform a select case inside the design view of the query and allowing it to choose which name to display.

My solution was to modify the query in VBA getting the criteria I needed and allowing it to dynamically change as I input various name parameters. Once its modified export that to excel.

As for the ```ALTER``` I perform that to modify the and have the Access Table contain the export to Excel

Comment: Once again all you said can be done without using tables or renaming and dropping columns with `ALTER`. Please edit your post and show (not tell) a specific routine to change queries. We can show you a solution without ever touching original tables.

Comment: I removed what I have currently and ONLY showing what i want to achieve

Comment: Sorry I was only focusing on Case 1

Comment: What is the underlying SQL for *queryName*? Do all cases use the same query object? You can query from a query: `SELECT col1, col2 FROM myquery`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use dynamic SQL and pass it a string in [QueryDef.SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-sql-property-dao) property:

**SQL** *(save below as a query object using Query Design, named mySavedQuery)*

```sql
SELECT * FROM myOriginalQueryOrTable
```

**VBA** *(see all references to mySavedQuery)*

```
Dim db   As Database
Dim qdef As QueryDef

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")              ' SQL QUERY ABOVE

' UPDATE SQL
Select Case displayName
     Case "Name 1"
     qdef.SQL = "SELECT name1 As [Name], ..." _
              & " FROM myOriginalQueryOrTable" _
              & " WHERE ..." _
              & " GROUP BY ..." _
              & " ORDER BY ..."

     Case Else
     MsgBox ("Name does not extist in system")
End Select

Set qdef = Nothing                                   ' SAVES NEW SQL
Set db = Nothing

' EXPORT TO EXCEL
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "mySavedQuery", _
      "C:\Path\To\Output\Spreadsheet.xlsx", True, "OUTPUT!"
```

Comment: I didnt know you could do it that way. I like it.
Would there be a way to not show items in the query? Say Name 2-5 which will still show up since they re not hidden.

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested and it seemed to work but the Transfer Spreadsheet command is having an issue.

`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "qry_Outfall_Report_DryWeather_All", fileName`
I get the error saying Circular reference caused by "qry_Outfall_Report_DryWeather_All"

Comment: I still get the circular reference issue. I did change the format to Excel12. I am using ArcGIS and they no longer support xlsx from 2016 so I have need to use xls allow me to read it with ARC

Comment: You absolutely cannot reference the *same* query name inside the *very* query. Use a different query in `QueryDef` assignment, maybe *querytemp*.

Comment: Would that be
```Dim qdef1 as QueryDef

set qdef1 = db.QueryDefs(qdef)
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, qdef1, "C:\Path\To\Output\Spreadsheet.xlsx", True, "OUTPUT!"```

Comment: A string must be go inside `QueryDefs` not QueryDef object and string is used in `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`. Please follow my solution. First, outside of VBA, create a new query of any name you want. Then use `Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")` and use string `"mySavedQuery"` in `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`.

Comment: That wouldnt overwrite the original query. Are you referencing the original query in the one outside VBA or leaving it blank to be populated?

Comment: Your SQL is incorrect as you are referencing the very query name as the source in `FROM` clause. Why overwrite anything? Keep original query as is. Use this Excel transfer process on a temporary query, *myTempQuery* (which will change with each last call of this code).

Comment: I am sorry to ask this but would you be able to show an example. I honestly am doing this for the first time and have never dove this far into it. I am more of a visual learner

Comment: See edit to first create a query and then reference it in code.